# ifelse() returning single value on TRUE test instead of arg 1

Tags: r

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the way ifelse is supposed to work...
I have a few tables that look like this (but much longer):

```
        Lean Turned Turn attempts
 [1,]   11      1             2
 [2,]   16      2             2
 [3,]   41      2             2
 [4,]   38      2             2
 [5,]   17      2             2
 [6,]   43      4             4
```

One is called X and it is unsorted
one is called L1LLwhole which is equal to X, but sorted by the "Lean" column by

```
 L1LLwhole <-X[order(X[,1]),]
```

now I'm making a list called goForL1 which is a subset of that list where Turn attempts is 2 or 4. I check to make sure at least one is 2 or 4 first or we get an error.

```
 ifelse(any((X[order(X[,1]),3]==2) | (X[order(X[,1]),3]==4)),
         L1LLwhole[(X[order(X[,1]),3]==2) | 
         (X[order(X[,1]),3]==4),],0)->goForL1
```

now the strange part is that even when the test evaluates to TRUE, and argument 1 evaluates to a table, the result of the entire statement is just "11"

isn't ifelse just supposed to return the exact argument as-is?

Comment: "isn't ifelse just supposed to return the exact argument as-is" No, it isn't. Re-read the very first sentence of the documentation at `?ifelse`.

Comment: what does "the same shape as test" mean? is that the length?
if "test" is always evaluated as true/false isn't the length always 1?

Comment: If the test evaluates to a vector of length one, you will only ever get a vector of length one back.

Comment: Regardless, if your test will always be of length one, `ifelse` is the wrong tool to use anyhow. You should just be using plain old `if - else`.

Comment: The `any` result has always length one. I believe you can get what you intend if you just remove it.